# Method GET not allowed when PATCH Null Value in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with PATCH Null Value in Django Rest Framework with Extend User Model. Please take a look my issues!

**Serializers:**, Profile is extend User Model

```
class UserEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    job_title = serializers.CharField(source='profile.job_title')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'job_title',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.save()
        if (validated_data.get('profile') is not None):
            profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
            profile = instance.profile
            profile.job_title = profile_data.get('job_title', profile.job_title)
```

**My viewsets:**

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserEditSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @detail_route(methods=['PATCH'])
    def edit(self, request):
        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        serializer = UserEditSerializer(user_obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Error'}, status=500)
```

**My api patch request to server:**

```
{
    "job_title": ""
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

**Error Photo**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying out the right url? I have seen this issue when I miss the / (slash) in the end of the url, the web server sends a redirect, and the subsequent request is a GET request, and not a PATCH

Comment: I dont think so because when I send request Json having data, example: `{
    "job_title": "Artist"
}`, it's normal, not error!

Comment: Place a `pdb` breakpoint in the `edit` method and look for the differences between when you call the endpoint with non-null and with null data. It's very likely that some kind of redirect is taking place...

Comment: It redirect is taking place, why when I send request JSON data username with null: `{ "username": "" }`, it's okay, not error.

Comment: I think i'm wrong in fucntion update of Serializers, bro!